# Keyword ALL in AVG function of PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have an employee table with their salaries.
What is the difference between:

```
SELECT AVG(salary)   
FROM employee;
```

and

```
SELECT AVG(ALL salary)    
FROM employee;
```

What does `ALL` do? Both cases give the same result.

Comment: Is `salary` nullable?

Comment: salary is not null column. My question is more What `ALL` do rather than this specific example.

Comment: I don't see the `ALL` keyword doing much here, since the `AVG()` function will already be applied over all records in the `employee` table.

Comment: It's the opposite of the `distinct` clause if I'm not mistaken, e.g. `count(all name)` vs. `count(distinct name)`. But all is the default. Similar to `union all` vs. `union distinct`

Comment: In union there is a very clear diffrance between union and union all, Because there could be duplicates, so you need to decide if you want them or not . Is it the same here?

Comment: Of course you can have duplicates in there as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) they are exactly the same regardless of the aggregation function:

> The first form of aggregate expression invokes the aggregate once for each input row. The second form is the same as the first, since ALL is the default.

Comment: Thanks that was what I looked for. All is the default so no need to mention it specificly.